# React -icons placed inside hexagon

Tags: css, reactjs

beginner in web development i have been trying to create this on CSS but failed  . i have tried using 5 react-icons to place in middle of hexagon  just like in Picture.As,
shown in Image given above[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLfsL.png)

**/Code/**

```
 <div class="hexagon">
     <{iconname/>
     <{iconname/>
     <{iconname/>
     <{iconname/>
     <{iconname/>
 </div>
```

```css
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #4da6ff;
  transform: r`otate(90deg);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `grid` and `grid-areas` in your hexagon class:

```
.hexagon {
  background: #4da6ff;

  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    'business-glossary  .               data-quality'
    '.                  data-ontologies .'
    'data-contracts     .               infra-code';
}

.bg {
  grid-area: business-glossary;
}

.dq {
  grid-area: data-quality;
}

.do {
  grid-area: data-ontologies;
}

.dc {
  grid-area: data-contracts;
}

.ic {
  grid-area: infra-code;
}
```

I also had to edit a little but your react code, I guess on your side the react code is right:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';

const IconName = (props) => {
  return (
    <img
      style={{ width: '25px' }}
      src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/1200px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png"
      alt="alt text"
      {...props}
    />
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="hexagon">
        <IconName className="bq" />
        <IconName className="dq" />
        <IconName className="do" />
        <IconName className="dc" />
        <IconName className="ic" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also removed the `clip-path` to prove that elements inside are placed correctly because the `clip-path` shape was looking weird.

Here a Stackblitz so you can check: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-u5dkhh?file=App.tsx